# I would like to create a centered 5 Image figure. How do I do this?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am trying to achieve this image positioning in Latex (see picture). Can somebody give some advice please?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Currently it is absolutely unclear, why you've set tag `tikz-positioning`. So my answer is not about TikZ but more general. If you need a more TikZ specific answer, please ask a new question with more details. BTW: I also do not think, that the question does depend on using overleaf. So IMHO this tag should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can, e.g., use `\parbox` or `minipage` so align two boxes with several images side by side. See a LaTeX introduction for more information about the command and the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.47\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  % \smallskip % if you want some vertical space
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  % \smallskip % if you want some vertical space
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.47\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  % \smallskip % if you want some vertical space
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: without \smallskip]

or after removing the `%` before the `\smallskip`:

[image: with \smallskip]

There are also some useful package, e.g.,   [`adjustbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) for extended box alignment or [`subcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) for using `sub-figures` inside `figure` environment.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped a lot. I used the mini page environment initially, but I struggled to position the two images to the right, centered with respect to the three images of the other column.

Comment: @MeDe Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).